# Is it possible to group a collection when each item could have more than one key?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a problem where a given item may have more than one key and I need to appear in both collections when groups. Is this possible?

The items may look something like this

```
class Item
{
   Category mainCat {get;set;}

   IEnumerable<Category> RelatedCategories {get;set;}

   String RefNumber {get;set;}
}

class Category
{
   String CatName {get;set;}
}
```

I need to group a collection of items by category, but if an item has a related category, it needs to appear in the group for the related category also.

So, as a simplest example I would have the following instance of item in a collection:

Ref: A1
Category: Cat_01
RelatedCategories: {Cat_02}

My desired output after grouping would be:

Key: Cat_01, Items {A1}
Key: Cat_02, Items {A1}

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Take you list append all related categories as new items and then group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in the following way.

```
var dictionary = item.RelatedCategories
     .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(item.mainCat, 1))
     .ToDictionary(c => c.CatName, c => item);
```

This will get the related categories and concatenate the main one and use `ToDictionary` to relate each category name to the given item.

If you are dealing with a list of items it gets more complicated because I would assume you need a `Dictionary<string, List<Item>>` in that case.

```
var dictionary = items.SelectMany(i => i.RelatedCategories
                                        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(i.mainCat, 1))
                                        .Select(c => new { c.CatName, Item = i}))
                      .GroupBy(a => a.CatName)
                      .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.ToList());
```

Here the internal query is creating an enumeration of anonymous classes that associate each category name to the item.  The `SelectMany` will flatten the enumerations into one.  Then the `GroupBy` will group those anonymous classes into groups based on the category name.  Then `ToDictionary` will create a dictionary where the key is the key of each group (the category name) and the value is a list of the items that are associated with the category name.

Comment: Oh, never thought of using `Enumerable.Repeat` to convert a single object into an enumeration. Nice trick!

Comment: Marvellous. Worked just the way that I needed it to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list of `Item` references and you want a dictionary that contains keys (categories) and related `Item` instances. The code below will do that.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Category, List<Item>>();
foreach (var item in ItemsList)
{
    AddToCategory(item, item.mainCat);
    foreach (var cat in item.RelatedCategories)
    {
        AddToCategory(item, cat);
    }
}

void AddToCategory(Item item, Category cat)
{
    List<Item> categoryItems;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(cat, out categoryItems))
    {
        categoryItems = new List<Item>();
        dict.Add(cat, categoryItems);
    }
    categoryItems.Add(item);
}
```

I don't see a way to do it with a simple LINQ expression, although it's quite possible there is a way.

Comment: Don't you need to pass the dictionary to the `AddToCategory` method, or are you assuming it's global.

Comment: @juharr: Here I'm assuming that it's global. Otherwise, yes, you'd have to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a LINQ query:

```
var query = from item in source
            from category in item.RelatedCategories.Concat(new[] { item.MainCat })
            group item by category.CatName into g
            select g;
```

Though that's one of the few cases where using LINQ probably isn't the most readable solution.